# Why is my output file empty?

Tags: java, file

I was working on a project for my AP Computer Science class that allows the user to sort music, when I came across a bug. The program parses a line in this format -> `year (tab) rank (tab) artist (tab) title (tab)`. It then can sort or filter the songs by year, rank, artist and/or title. This information is loaded through an input file that is formatted like:

```
2008    50  Ashley Tisdale  He Said, She Said
2008    123 Taylor Swift    Teardrops On My Guitar
2008    233 Finger Eleven   Paralyzer
2008    258 Paramore    Misery Business
...
```

I'm not sure how to convey my problem without revealing all my code, so here it is.

```
import java.util.*;
import java.io.*;
import java.util.Arrays;

public class GazillionSongs {
   public static void main(String[] args) throws FileNotFoundException {
      System.out.println("Hello and welcome to my AP Computer Science Music Sorting Project!"); 
      Scanner kb = new Scanner(System.in);

      System.out.print("Enter the input file: ");
      String in = kb.nextLine();
      Scanner inFile = new Scanner(new File(in));

      System.out.print("Enter sort/filter command: ");
      String command = kb.nextLine();

      System.out.print("Enter an output file: ");
      String out = kb.nextLine();

      File f = new File(out);

      if (f.exists()) {
         System.out.println("Error: output file already exists...");
      } else {
         PrintStream outFile = new PrintStream(new File(out));

         ArrayList<String> lines = new ArrayList<String>();

         while (inFile.hasNextLine()) {
            String line = inFile.nextLine();
            lines.add(line);  
         }

         ArrayList<Song> songs = new ArrayList<Song>();

         Scanner allCommands = new Scanner(command);

         for(int i = 0; i < lines.size(); i++) {
            int year = 0;
            int rank = 0;
            String artist = "";
            String title = "";
            Song song = new Song(year, rank, artist, title);
            song.parse(lines.get(i));
            songs.add(song);
         }

         SongCollection songCollection = new SongCollection(songs);

         while (allCommands.hasNext()) {
            for(int i = 0; i < songs.size(); i++) {
               String command2 = allCommands.next();
               String[] tokens = command2.split(":");
               if (tokens[0].equals("year")) {
                  int min = 0;
                  int max = 0;
                  Range range = new Range(min, max);
                  range.parse(tokens[1]);
                  songCollection.filterYear(range);
               }
               if (tokens[0].equals("rank")) {
                  int min = 0;
                  int max = 0;
                  Range range = new Range(min, max);
                  range.parse(tokens[1]);
                  songCollection.filterRank(range);
               }
               if (tokens[0].equals("artist")) {
                  songCollection.filterArtist(tokens[1]);
               }
               if (tokens[0].equals("title")) {
                  songCollection.filterTitle(tokens[1]);
               }
            }
         }
         outFile.print(songCollection.toString());         
      }
   }                  
}
```

and

```
    import java.io.*;
    import java.util.*;

    public class Song {
       private static int year;
       private static int rank;
       private static String artist;
       private static String title;

       public Song(int year, int rank, String artist, String title) {
          this.year = year;
          this.rank = rank;
          this.artist = artist;
          this.title = title;
       }

       public static Song parse(String s) {
          String[] tokens = s.split("\t");
          year = Integer.parseInt(tokens[0]);
          rank = Integer.parseInt(tokens[1]);
          artist = tokens[2];
          title = tokens[3];
          Song song = new Song(year, rank, artist, title);
          return song;
       }

       public int getYear() {
          return this.year;
       }

       public int getRank() {
          return this.rank;
       }

       public String getArtist() {
          return this.artist;
       }

       public String getTitle() {
          return this.title;
       }

       public String toString() {
          String convertString = year + "/t" + rank + "/t" + artist + "/t" + title;
          return convertString;
       }     
    }
```

and

```
import java.util.*;

public class Range {
   private int min;
   private int max;

   public int getMin() { 
      return min; 
   }
   public int getMax() { 
      return max; 
   }

   public Range(int  min, int max) {
      this.min = min;
      this.max = max;
   }

   public static Range parse(String s) {
      String[] range = s.split("-");
      int min = Integer.parseInt(range[0]);
      int max = 1;

      try {
         max = Integer.parseInt(range[1]);
      } catch(ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException err10) {
         max = Integer.parseInt(range[0]);
      }  

      if(min > max){
         return new Range(max,min);   
      } else {
         return new Range(min,max);
      }
   }

   public boolean contains(int n) {
      if(n <= max && n >= min) {
         return true;
      } else {
         return false;
      }
   }
}
```

and

```
import java.util.*;

public class SongCollection {

   private ArrayList<Song> songs = new ArrayList<Song>();

   public SongCollection(ArrayList<Song> songs) {
      this.songs = songs;
   }

   public ArrayList<Song> getList() {
      return songs;
   }

   public void filterYear(Range r) {
      for(int i = 0; i < songs.size(); i++) {
         if(!r.contains(songs.get(i).getYear())) {
            songs.remove(i);
            i--;
         }
      }
   }

   public void filterRank(Range r) {
      for(int i = 0; i < songs.size(); i++) {
         if(!r.contains(songs.get(i).getRank())) {
            songs.remove(i);
            i--;
         }
      }
   }

   public void filterArtist(String s) {
      for(int i = 0; i < songs.size(); i++) {
         if(!songs.get(i).getArtist().toLowerCase().contains(s.toLowerCase())) {
            songs.remove(i);
            i--;
         }
      }
   }

   public void filterTitle(String s) {
      for(int i = 0; i < songs.size(); i++) {
         if(!songs.get(i).getTitle().toLowerCase().contains(s.toLowerCase())) {
            songs.remove(i);
            i--;
         }
      }
   }

   public void sortYear() {
      for(int i = 1; i <= songs.size(); i++) {
         Song temp = songs.get(i);
         int j;
         for (j = i - 1; j >= 0 && temp.getYear() < songs.get(j).getYear(); j--) {
            songs.set((j + 1), songs.get(j));
            songs.set((j), temp);
         }
      }
   }

   public void sortRank() {
      for(int i = 1; i <= songs.size(); i++) {
         Song temp = songs.get(i);
         int j;
         for (j = i - 1; j >= 0 && temp.getRank() < songs.get(j).getRank(); j--) {
            songs.set((j + 1), songs.get(j));
            songs.set((j), temp);
         }
      }
   }

   public void sortTitle() {
      for(int i = 1; i <= songs.size(); i++) {
         Song temp = songs.get(i);
         int j;
         for (j = i - 1; j >= 0 && temp.getTitle().toLowerCase().compareTo(songs.get(j).getTitle().toLowerCase()) < 0; j--) {
            songs.set((j + 1), songs.get(j));
            songs.set((j), temp);
         }
      }
   }

   public void sortArtist() {
      for(int i = 1; i <= songs.size(); i++) {
         Song temp = songs.get(i);
         int j;
         for (j = i - 1; j >= 0 && temp.getArtist().toLowerCase().compareTo(songs.get(j).getArtist().toLowerCase()) < 0; j--) {
            songs.set((j + 1), songs.get(j));
            songs.set((j), temp);
         }
      }
   }

   public String toString() {
      String stringOfSong = "";
      for(int i = 0; i < songs.size(); i++) {
         stringOfSong += songs.get(i).toString() + "\n";
      }
      return stringOfSong;
   }
}
```

Why is the file blank when I output the information?

Comment: "I'm not sure how to convey my problem without revealing all my code, " well, do you think that it is Song that is relevant to the problem? You can determine this by replacing writing songs with writing things that don't need the other classes, e.g. strings.

Answer (score 2):

You never close your `outFile`. Add `outfile.close()` add the end of your program.

Comment: Or use try-with-resources to do it automagically, provided you are using Java 7 or newer.

Comment: Uh that didn't fix my problem. Do you have any other suggestions?

Comment: @Jens Uh that didn't fix my problem. Do you have any other suggestions?

Comment: @KingZuko Try to use `System.out.println(songCollection.toString());` to see if you get any result.

Comment: @Jens nothing outputted from that, I have been trying to trace why this happened but I just cannot find a reason.

Comment: @Jens so you copy and pasted my code, and something outputted from that?

Comment: @KingZuko yes there are some lines in the file.